# inpaint() does not produce expected result. Why?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.2

Here I am trying to remove glare.

This is my original image.
[image]

and this is my mask image.
[image]

I used the following line of code to use `inpaint()`:

```
inpaint(image, vthresh, out, 5.0, CV_INPAINT_NS); //CV_INPAINT_TELEA , CV_INPAINT_NS
```

But I do not understand why I cannot get any effect result using `inpaint()`.
Can anyone please point out the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Please try: `cv::bitwise_not(vthresh, vthresh);` before the call to `inpaint`.

Comment: cv::bitwise_not(vthresh, vthresh);
this just invert image.

Comment: Yes sure it inverts your mask, I was just thinking that maybe your mask is wrong.

Comment: I THINK mask is correct. there is something else that I am missing.

Comment: Give it at least a try...

Comment: Yes I tried that bitwise_not().

Comment: thanks for editing my question.

Comment: Resize the mask to image size.

Comment: Well, image size and mask size .. both are size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int args, char** argv)
{
   //Read the image
   Mat img = imread("/Desktop/apple.png", -1);
   //create inpaint mask the size of original image
   Mat inpaintMask = img.clone();
   //convert mask from rgb to gray
   cv::cvtColor(inpaintMask, inpaintMask, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
   // convert mask from gray to binary by thresholding, you can play with 170 and 255 args to achieve desired mask
   cv::threshold(inpaintMask, inpaintMask, 170, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
   Mat inpainted;
   //finally call inpaint function and pass the args
   inpaint(img, inpaintMask, inpainted, 3, INPAINT_TELEA);

   imshow("image", img);
   imshow("mask", inpaintMask);
   imshow("inpainted image", inpainted);
   cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

**Edit: Added headers and main function to make it a standalone file**

Comment: I tried it . I am still getting binary image. not expected result.;

Comment: i cannot find reason why it is still giving binary image.

Comment: @Abc Copy and paste the new code in a separate file and compile it with g++.

Comment: @Abc What do you mean "how come"? Study the code, google the functions that you don't understand, read them in opencv documentation. If you still have any questions then ask them here.